# Corona SDK native.playVideo() can not play video on several Android devices

Tags: android, ios, video, lua, coronasdk

When I test my app on Android devices several of them can not play video file (on iOS device everything work perfect) and shows an error like "Can not play video".

I think this error depends of Android version...

How to fix this error?

If it's impossible to play video on all Android devices then how can I catch this error, I wouldn't like my app show this error message?

Here is my code:

```
videoObj = native.newVideo( centerX, centerY, 320, 480 )        
videoPath = "video/video1.mp4"

if (system.getInfo("platformName") == "Android") then
  videoObj:load(system.pathForFile(videoPath))      
else
  videoObj:load(videoPath)      
end         
videoObj:play()
```

Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0):

yes, it'll work for ios,

On Android the video objects do not rotate.

If you require video support on other platforms, then you must use the media.playVideo() function instead.

Here is complete and perfect Corona Documentation for it. Also read its "OverView" section it'll have all details.

http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/media/playVideo.html

media.playVideo( "Movie.m4v", true, onComplete )

If second parameter is true, then the user can adjust playback, e.g. start, stop, seek, etc.

Please try using media.stop()

Hope it helps you. Please let me know if we have to go with another solution.

Comment: thanks, but by "tap" listener in Runtime I should close video. How can I close it using media?

Comment: I have updated my post. Also please check overview section, they suggest us to stop/start using showControls parameter in media.playVideo()

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code: Hope this will help you.

```
local onComplete = function(event)
   print( "video session ended" )
end
media.playVideo( "Movie.m4v", true, onComplete )
```

Note: You have to assign android permission in your build.setting file.

Comment: thanks, but by "tap" listener in Runtime I should close video. How can I close it using media?

Comment: Here is the api provided by corona lab. Let me if there is any other issue. corona:https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/native/newVideo.html